# IAP non-renewing subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app

I have some issue regarding IAP. I use IAP non-renewing subscription. This working fine. but when restore transection at that time return always 0 id. So it is possible restore non-renewing subscription without use local server or iCloud.

received restored transactions: 0

Thanks

Comment: can you tell me how you implement non-renewing subscription and how to validate receipt i want to implement it in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In non-renewing subscription not restore functionality available but restore button compulsory.

Answer (score 2):

You are responsible for restoring non-renewing subscriptions.

From the Apple [In-App Purchasing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW5)

> - **Non-renewable subscriptions.** Subscriptions that don’t involve delivering episodic content. Examples include access to a database of historic photos or a collection of flight maps. It’s your app’s responsibility to make the subscription available on all of the user’s devices and to let users restore the purchase. This product type is often used when your users already have an account on your server that you can use to identify them when restoring content. Expiration and the duration of the subscription are also left to your app (or your server) to implement and enforce.

If your users are to be able to restore their access to previously purchased subscriptions then you will need them to create an account on your server.